# Query not sorting DESC

Tags: wp-query

I am using the following query:

```
<?php $postslist = new WP_Query('meta_key=Ordermetakey&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC&posts_per_page=5');
```

To sort a small post list on the frontpage to show latest new. It needs to order them by a meta key and do this DESC. The strange thing is it shows the posts ASC even though i have put ASC in this query.

The value of the meta key is a date - time stamp:
Example: 120403  = 03-04-2012

How can i make it work?

Comment: You must put DESC in your query of course but I believe you have another problem. 120403 is not a timestamp. The best solution is to save the date as a timestamp.

Comment: If sorting by date use a time-stamp or store the date in `YYYYMMDD` format. The format you are using won't sort correctly. Consider the 11th November 2011 and 1st January 2012 .

Comment: But i currently use YYMMDD and it works with the Smart Sort plugin.

Comment: Just because you are doing it now and it works in a specific case does not make it the best way to do things. You should be storing your date as a unix timestamp, which is the number of seconds since the unix epoch. This is the most reliable way to sort dates and the most flexible format for the data.

Comment: Yes but my question is why does my WP Query cant order things by a custom field.

Comment: Storing in `YYYYMMDD` is fine - but in the example above you are storing it as `DDMMYYYY`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to order it DESC put DESC in your query.

```
$postslist = new WP_Query('meta_key=Ordermetakey&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=5');
```

Comment: Yes was an example. Also tried DESC but it just shows ASC.